# Is it possible to "marry" Eclipse PHP with Java EE?

Tags: php, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I've already got Eclipse for PHP-developers installed. Must I install a new version for Java EE, or can I "marry" it into the PHP version, for instance trough updates or plug-ins? The reason I ask is 1) I want to save space ('cause I'm greedy), 2) I want to not have to switch programs all the time ('cause I'm lazy). :)

- Is it possible?
- How do you do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. get yourself eclipse classic
2. go to *Help > Install new software*
3. install PDT things
4. install Java EE things
5. use it while switching the perspectives

P.S. you might want to look into Aptana's eclipse plugin  as alternative to PDT, while you're at it . Some people prefer it (ST2 user .. no real stake in this)

Comment: Seems like it is possible to install new software on the PHP version also. Any special reason to get Classic over other versions? (Reason I want Java is because I plan to program for Android.)

Comment: @Kebman , mostly because it is a *clean slate* version of eclipse. Kinda personal preference. By the way, as for Android, there is one other eclispe based thing you might want to look at: Titanium Studio. It would let you write android/iphone apps with PHP. But i am not sure how easy would be to add JavaEE support on top of it. And it has one other stupid problem: cannot use offline. But you still might want to see what it is about.

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible to install both the PDT Eclipse and the Jave EE eclipse into the same folder i.e. merge the plugin folders.

Then you can use both features in the same Eclipse version.

Comment: I would agree with this. Pick one to be the sole installation and copy the contents of the plugins folder from the other copy into this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can add all the Java EE plugins and add the Java EE functionality to your copy. I actually did this the other way around. I started with Java EE and added the PDT php tools to my eclipse and it works fine.